# How to make peanut (cake) cookies in blender

Tags: modeling, faces, edges, fluid-simulation, bevel

hope every one is good. I am using blender from last two years but this time stuck in modeling a cake cookies. Picture is attached your help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.[image]

Comment: Hello, welcome to Blender SA!  If you have specific technical questions this is the place, but your request falls more along the lines of a tutorial.  Youtube, Google, and BlenderCookie are all good places to search for such inquiries.

Comment: Your are right a lot tutorials on youtube. But i am stuck at curves if add sub-division modifier ir changes shape.

Comment: Hello, what part exactly are your struggling with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a cylinder, scale on Z, select the edge ring and *Select > Checker Deselect* in order to select one edge out of two:

[image]

Scale the selected edges on XY only:

[image]

Bevel the edge ring:

[image]

Scale the bottom, inset or extrude the top face and scale down:

[image]

Add some edge loops before adding *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]